# Slice Spark’s DataFrame SQL by row (pyspark)

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark's Dataframe parquet file that can be read by spark as follows

```
df = sqlContext.read.parquet('path_to/example.parquet')
df.registerTempTable('temp_table')
```

I want to slice my dataframe, `df`, by row (i.e. equivalent to `df.iloc[0:4000], df.iloc[4000:8000]` etc. in Pandas dataframe) since I want to convert each small chunks to pandas dataframe to work on each later on. I only know how to do it by using `sample` random fraction i.e.

```
df_sample = df.sample(False, fraction=0.1) # sample 10 % of my data
df_pandas = df_sample.toPandas()
```

I would be great if there is a method to slice my dataframe `df` by row. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [monotonically_increasing_id()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id) to add an ID column to your dataframe and use that to get a working set of any size.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

# add an index column
df = df.withColumn('id', f.monotonically_increasing_id())

# Sort by index and get first 4000 rows
working_set = df.sort('id').limit(4000)
```

Then, you can remove the working set from your dataframe using [subtract()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract).

```
# Remove the working set, and use this `df` to get the next working set
df = df.subtract(working_set)
```

Rinse and repeat until you're done processing all rows. Not the ideal way to do things, but it works. Consider filtering out your Spark data frame to be used in Pandas.